# Select rows having same column value more than 3 times

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table called `Theater(Sn, SeatVacant)`

```
e.g SN SEATVACANT
    1  Y
    2  Y
    3  N
    .  .
    .  .
  100  Y
```

I want to book 3 seats(should be continuous). How can i get the continuous vacant seat.

Comment: *gaps-and-islands* - E.g. [Find “n” consecutive free numbers from table](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36943/find-n-consecutive-free-numbers-from-table)

Comment: If this really represents a theater, then I doubt that there is a single row of 100 seats. So you probably also need to take into account which seats are numerically contiguous but not physically next to each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select f1.sn, f2.sn, f3.sn from Theater f1
inner join Theater f2 on f1.sn=f2.sn + 1 
inner join Theater f3 on f1.sn=f3.sn + 2
where f1.SEATVACANT='Y' and f2.SEATVACANT='Y' and f3.SEATVACANT='Y'
```

Comment: Thanks. It works.... But it is a static solution, can i able to do it dynamic. for e.g x number of continuous vacant seat

Answer (score 1):

```
with tablenewkey as(
select ROW_NUMBER() over(order by f1.sn) newkey, f1.* from theater f1
),
nbplacevacant as (
select 3 as NbrowByGroup
),
calculdiff as (
select f1.*, isnull(f3.newkey, 0) newkeylastN, f1.newkey - isnull(f3.newkey, 0) DiffYWithLasN 
from tablenewkey f1
outer apply
(
select top 1 *  from tablenewkey f2
where f2.newkey<f1.newkey and f2.SEATVACANT='N'
order by f2.newkey desc
) f3
where f1.SEATVACANT='Y' and (f1.newkey - isnull(f3.newkey, 0))>=(select NbrowByGroup from nbplacevacant)
),
possibilite as (
select f0.*, f1.newkey Groupement, f1.DiffYWithLasN
from tablenewkey f0 inner join calculdiff f1 
on f0.newkey between (f1.newkey - DiffYWithLasN +1) and  f1.newkey
where f0.SEATVACANT='Y'
)
select newkey, sn, Groupement, DENSE_RANK() over(order by Groupement)    PossiblilityRang from possibilite
order by groupement, sn
```

Answer (score 1):

Like this, if you want a dynamic solution:

```
--Theater(Sn, SeatVacant)

DECLARE @ContiguougsSeats AS INT
SET @ContiguougsSeats = 4

SELECT  Sn, ' to ', Sn+@ContiguougsSeats-1
FROM    Theater As t1
WHERE    t1.Sn+@ContiguougsSeats-1 <= (Select MAX(Sn) From Theater)
  AND   NOT EXISTS(
    Select  *
    From    Theater As t2
    Where   t2.Sn Between t1.Sn AND t1.Sn+@ContiguougsSeats-1
      And   t2.SeatVacant = 'N'
    )
```

Comment: Nice, juste a little error when you tape your code, t2.SEATVACANT = 'N'

Comment: @Esperento57 Thanks, fixed now.